# Enum methods in Java and C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Consider the following Enum Class in Java:

```
package com.gousslegend.deepov;

public enum Color
{
    WHITE, BLACK;

    private Color opposite;

    static
    {
        WHITE.opposite = BLACK;
        BLACK.opposite = WHITE;
    }

    public Color getOppositeColor()
    {
        return opposite;
    }
}
```

- How can I achieve the same thing with C++11?
- Is is possible to have enum methods with C++11?
- Should I put my enum in a separate class/file with C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve the same thing with C++11?

In C++ you would be better off defining an `enum`, along with a free-standing function:

```
enum Color {BLACK, WHITE};
Color getOppositeColor(Color c) {
    static Color opposite[] = {WHITE, BLACK};
    return opposite[c];
}
```

If you are set on modeling Java exactly, make a class with two static members `BLACK` and `WHITE`, and use it instead of `enum`. The use would be limited, though: for instance, you wouldn't be able to use your `enum` values in `switch` cases.

> Is is possible to have enum methods with C++11?

No

> Should I put my enum in a separate class/file with C++?

You should put `enum` definition and a function prototype in a header; implementation of the function goes in a separate C++ file.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. No it does not have to model Java exactly. Concerning your code, how can I fit that into a Color.hpp file and a Color.cpp file?

Comment: @Romain `enum` goes into the header, along with the prototype (i.e. `extern Color getOppositeColor(Color c);` forward declaration). The function itself goes to the cpp file.

Comment: I guess it's not possible the name the file Color.hpp/Color.cpp. I have got the following error message: 'Color::Color' has the same name as the class in which it is declared. https://github.com/RomainGoussault/Deepov/blob/master/src/Color.hpp

Comment: @Romain The problem there is that the name of the nested class, struct, or enum may not be the same as the name of the outer class. In my example both the `Color` enum and the `getOppositeColor` function are declared at the top level, i.e. outside any classes.

Answer (score 0):

C++'s enums are simple enumerated values, they're not full-fledged classes (enum classes in C++ only provide some additional type-safety).

I would take the following approach to implement the equivalent to how Java's enums are used here:

```
// Header file

class Color {

    Color *opposite_p;

public:
    Color(Color *opposite_pArg) : opposite_p(opposite_pArg) {}

    Color &opposite() { return *opposite_p; }

    static Color WHITE, BLACK;
};

// .C file

Color Color::WHITE(&BLACK);
Color Color::BLACK(&WHITE);
```

Then, `Color::WHITE.opposite()` returns `Color::BLACK`, and `COLOR::BLACK.oppsoite()` returns `Color::WHITE`.